# Ignoring values in Go's range

Tags: go, memory, range

I have a question about Go's `range` and the way in which ignoring return values work.

As the documentations stands, each iteration, `range` produces two values - an index and a copy of the current element, so if during an iteration we want to change a field in the current elmenet, or the element itself we have to reference it via `elements[index]`, because `elment` is just a copy (assuming that the loop looks something like this `for index, element := range elements`).

Go also allows to ignore some of the return values using `_`, so we can write `for index, _ := elements`.

But it got me thinking. Is Go smart enough to actually don't make a copy when using the `_` in `range`? If it isn't, then if elements in `elements` are quite big and we have multiple processes/go-routines running our code, we are wasting memory, and it would be better to use looping based on `len(elements)`.

Am I right?

EDIT

We can also use

`for index := range elements`

which seems like a good alternative.

Comment: If the elements are pointers to something you get a copy of the pointer, which allows you to mutate the value it points to.

Comment: @mkopriva yeah, but lets just assume that `elements` is a slice, and elements in `elements` are just ordinary objects

Comment: then use index, and `_` as far as i know omits allocation, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: That's what I though in the first place, but you can write a function that returns multiple values, prepare the return values inside the function's body (allocate memory) and return them. So, let the function be called `someFunction`, it return two values, then someone uses your function, but ignores one of the return values - that means that allocation happens, but the return value was never used. That's why `range` got me thinking

Comment: This is an implementation detail, meaning it may vary from version to version, or between gc and gccgo, etc. In reality, any implementation is likely to optimize away any unused allocations, so it likely won't matter. But the best way to answer a question like this is with a benchmark or profiling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `for range` construct may produce up to 2 values, but not necessarily 2 (it can also be a single index value or map key or value sent on channel, or even none at all).

Quoting from [Spec: For statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)

> If the range expression is a channel, at most one iteration variable is permitted, otherwise there may be up to two.

Continuing the quote:

> If the last iteration variable is the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier), the range clause is equivalent to the same clause without that identifier.

What this means is that:

```
for i, _ := range something {}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for i := range something {}
```

And another quote from Spec: For statements, a little bit down the road:

> For an array, pointer to array, or slice value `a`, the index iteration values are produced in increasing order, starting at element index `0`. **If at most one iteration variable is present, the range loop produces iteration values from `0` up to `len(a)-1` and does not index into the array or slice itself.**

So the extra blank identifier in the first case does not cause extra allocations or copying, and it's completely unnecessary and useless.